# If two columns are foreign key in the same column of primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If two columns are foreign key in the same column of primary key, how to set that those foreign keys to not have the same values.

Comment: Don't.  Just use two columns.  Why "combine" them -- it will just make it harder to work with in the future.  Also it is possible I don't understand your question -- if that is the case you should provide more detail -- like the data model for the 3 tables you are talking about and their relationships.

Comment: Don't know if I get this correctly, but you might use kind of `WhatTypeIsThis` column and define an index or a check constraint on a combination of them.

Comment: @Shnugo Type of Column is Integer, and those columns dont allow same values. for example 1 1 or 2 2

Comment: @muhamed.h please provide sample data